# Flutter How to search a spesific map inside of list?

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dictionary, listview

I have 3 selectable item on my UI.
I created these with `ListViewBuilder`. My goal is upload  the `selectedItem`'s to Firebase. Anyway, in example;

```
List<Map<String?, dynamic>> selectedItems = List.empty(growable: true);
```

List is gonna be like this right before uploading Firebase:

```
List selectedItems = [
      {
        'title': selectedItem[index].title,
        'price': selectedItem[index].price,
      },
    ];
```

This has to be my `selectedItems` list.

And I upload this list as `Map` like this:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> updatedData = {'items': selectedItems};
```

This has to be like this in order to Firebase design.

First of all when the user has clicked to item I want to check `selectedItems` list.
Here is my code but it doesn't work at all:

```
if (selectedServices.contains(
                           [{
                           'title': selectedItem[index].title,
                           'price': selectedItem[index].price,
                           }])
```

The problem is right up here. After this check (also it's always passing because not working) I try to remove same items from `selectedItems` with this code:

```
selectedServices.removeWhere((item) => mapEquals(
                                            item,
                                            ({
                                              'title': selectedItem[index].title,
                                              'price': selectedItem[index].price,
                                            })));
```

But it doesn't work too because of the check always passing false. After these steps, my onPressed function working just on this `else` code bloc.

```
else
        {
                selectedServices.addAll([{
                selectedItem[index].title:
                selectedItem[index].price
    }
    ]);}
```

A little summary;
`.contains` method not working like this. If there is another way to set list of maps, just let me learn that. This is important for me but I can't figure it out last few days.
And lastly, can you explain answer how it works for Dart ?

Comment: are title and price and all other item values in the map primitive types?

Comment: instead of `mapEquals` you could also try [`MapEquality.equals`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/MapEquality-class.html)

Comment: Yes, other elements has the title and price too.

Comment: Also mapEquals work  if I try it  alone with another button. I think problem is checking map inside of list.

Comment: well, there are 3 possible points of failure here, imo, `removeWhere`, `mapEquals`, or the equal check between your key-value pairs. in the first one im relatively confident, the second i dont rly know, its also unclear from which package you get that function. the third one: if your maps contain any complex / non-primitive keys/values keep in mind, that equality check is per default done via comparing references, not values.

Comment: Still not solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Focus of the question changed, so this answer now tries to achieve a `contains` like functionality for lists with complex items.

For a custom equality check a similar functionality to `contains` can be achieved via `any`:

```dart
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';

void main() {
  final map1 = {
    'title': 'item1',
    'price': 12.34,
  };

  final map2 = {
    'title': 'item2',
    'price': 3.45,
  };

  final list = [map1, map2];

  final test1 = list.any((item)=>MapEquality().equals(item, {
    'title': 'item1',
    'price': 12.34,
  }));

  print(test1);
  
  final test2 = list.any((item)=>MapEquality().equals(item, {
    'title': 'item3',
    'price': 14.34,
  }));

  print(test2);
}
```

print is:

```
true
false
```

you could run into precision issues with doubles, though, or if you are using complex key-value pairs in your maps.

Comment: I didn't face to problem with ```removeWhere``` method. I couldn't handle with ```.contains``` method.

Comment: How can we use ```.contains``` method for searching map inside of list? That is the problem I think.

Comment: you dont, `contains` checks for reference equality on complex objects. so either you have the SAME map (as in same reference, not just equal values) or you do some custom equality check with `where`, `firstWhere` or `any` to find an element that may match your "equals" criteria ...

Comment: edited my answer to show a way with `any`

Comment: Man, you saved my day! Thank you so much. I am an intermediate level amateur for developing. I never went to school for software but sometimes I disturb people someone like you for kind a problem like this. I am really really appreciate you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you try to check if array contains other array in this code:

```
if (selectedServices.contains(
                           [{
                           'title': selectedItem[index].title,
                           'price': selectedItem[index].price,
                           }])
```

?

Try to check with one item in parameter-list:

```
if (selectedServices.contains(
          {'title': selectedItem[index].title}
    ))
```

Comment: I already checking that as you can see in my question. Your second code bloc not working.